# SQL Failover Cluster IP Migration

Tags: sql-server, cluster, failovercluster

I have a four node cluster setup which I need to migrate from subnet A to subnet B. The cluster has roughly 12 instances running on it. I've found articles to update the SQL Cluster IP, but I've got more problems or need more information regarding the logistics of the migration. My initial plan was to do this:

1. Connect cable or create virtual NIC connected to subnet B on all hosts
2. Begin moving instances to subnet B
3. Move cluster IP to subnet B
4. Delete subnet A from any listed cluster networks

Until all of the instances are moved, there will be a period when only one NIC has a default gateway, which may be an issue it would seem to be. Other than scheduling a complete downtime and just doing it all at once and getting rid of subnet A immediately, what's the best route to accomplish this migration?